# How to contact Facebook application users without token

Tags: facebook

My Facebook application has a few thousand users but they have not visited the application for a long time and I don't have access tokens for them. I do have their uid's.

How could I make contact to my application users?

I used to use the Notification.sendEmail but it is now deprecated and won't send any emails. I have email permission for all of the users but I didn't store the users email address earlier because I used that function. I should have stored the addresses.

I have understood that all use of new Graph api require access token. So my option would be to use the old Rest api. But is there a method that could be used in a situation like this?

Comment: See the "App to User Request" section of this document: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/requests/

Comment: Looks promising. Need to try it tomorrow.

Comment: Can't you still retrieve the email addresses using the app access token? (assuming they haven't subsequently removed the app)

Comment: Thanks Igy! If you want to add that as an answer I will accept that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to still retrieve the email addresses of the users who granted your app the `email` [Permission](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions/) if they haven't subsequently removed it - you can do this with the App Access Token (see the [Authentication](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/) docs for more info)

Make a call to `/<USER ID>?fields=email` to get the address